# Botón "cargar más" contenidos

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony2, twig

Actualmente tengo una pagina con contenidos tipo Blog pero tengo paginado todo, en total tengo 23 páginas y no es muy amigable con el usuario, mi idea es poner un botón de cargar o ver más en lugar de la paginación, pero no quiero poner un scroll infinito. Cada página tiene su URL por ejemplo:

```
www.miblog.com/experiencias  
www.miblog.com/experiencias/2 
www.miblog.com/experiencias/3
```

Y así sucesivamente, cada contenido tiene su div respectivo, he leido sobre algo del evento load() pero no me queda muy claro como puedo hacerlo funcionar, agradezco su ayuda

Comment: debes colocar un ejemplo minimo de tu codigo y el resultado esperado `load()` es un evento que se ejecuta al cargar el `documento`  o un `elemento` lo que requieres es `ajax` y que al dar click traiga el siguiente resultado y lo agrege debajo del ya existente! `append`

Comment: Lo que necesitas es paginación, necesitas paginar tus resultados.